# What's the minimum number of clades for a valid phylogenetic regression?

Tags: mixed-model, sample-size, phylogeny

I have a dataset with some phenotype measurements of a handful of birds (~ 150 individuals of ~10 species) and I would like to run a mixed effect model on this.

Intuitively I would have tried to add a phylogeny in my model, but...
Is it valid to perform a phylogenetic regression with such a small number of clades? Is there a rule of thumb to decide when to include a phylogeny in a model?